# ng-repeat runs twice (Angular)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Consider the following ng-repeat:

```
<p ng-repeat="item in items">
    <span ng-bind="getName(item)"></span>
</p>
```

Now the weird thing is that if I have an array with 10 items, the getName is called 20 times

Checkout this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/8592/)

Can someone explain why this is happening. Performance wise this might be a killing (I can imagine)

Comment: Darn, but that is weird!

Comment: I am sorry but in your fiddle you have 4 items and getName is called 4 times. Correct ?

Comment: No, it is called 8 times. I just tried it. Replace "console.log" with "alert" and you will see it.

Comment: ah ok. let me try it.

Comment: Yeah, if I hadn't seen the fiddle, I would not have believe it. :-)

Comment: that is typical. that is just how angular works.

Comment: Check out this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9682092/databinding-in-angularjs/9693933#9693933

Comment: @DanielA.White is it something about the directive running pre-link and post-link phases? Or am I barking up the wrong tree?

Comment: @deitch i think its part of the digest cycle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is standard behavior for angular. Angular runs dirty checking on values and will run at least twice to ensure that the value hasn't changed.

EDIT:

In order to avoid this kind of behavior I would suggest mapping this name in the controller, this will only be evaluated once for each item:

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    ...
    $scope.items.forEach(function(item) {
        item.name = getName(item);
    });
    ...
});


<p ng-repeat="item in items">
     <span>{{item.name}}</span>
</p>
```